# Number of answers depending on time asked

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In the SE blog [The Best Time to Ask a Stack Overflow Question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/) the following graph of No. of questions answered vs. hour GMT:

[image]

This shows that (roughly) questions asked at 1600 are almost 3x more likely to be answered than ones at 0700.

- **This statistic was made in 2009 - are things different now?**
- **Is there anything done to alleviate this mismatch?**

Comment: What would you propose SE should do about this? Forcibly migrate programmers into understaffed timezones?

Comment: You can run your own queries on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com), it'll even produce graphs for you.

Comment: @MadScientist I thought SE would have invented time travel by now. Alternatively pushing unanswered questions from those times up the Top Questions list in preference.

Comment: If you're concerned about questions in some timezones receiving fewer answers, you have to look at a different data set. From this data you can't see if simply fewer questions are asked during that time, or if there are really fewer people answering.

Comment: @MadScientist that graph is actually number of users on the site.  quote from link:  "What is SO's peak time of day in terms of number of users on the site? "

Answer (score 6):

> This statistic was made in 2009 - are things different now?

This is more or less the same.

[I made a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/196622/254511/submit-hour-of-questions-and-answers) which shows the breakdown of questions and answers throughout the day, so you can see on-demand.

As of 2014-05-23, these are the results (for the entire history of the site):

> [image]

If someone found a problem with my query, edit it and post the new link here.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything done to alleviate this mismatch?

What would you suggest?

We can't force people to be on Stack Overflow 24/7 so your question will only get answered when there are people around who potentially know the answer. Most people search in their interesting tags so as long as you write a good question and tag it appropriately there's a good chance that it will be seen by the right people.

Promoting your question via the share link on Twitter, Google+ or even Facebook is another technique you can use to increase the chance of the right people seeing it.

Another thing you can do is to try to find out when the experts in your field are active and to ask your question around these times to increase the chance that someone will see it.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, pushing unanswered questions from those time zones up the Top Questions page during peak times would potentially balance out the mismatch?

Comment: @dav_i - It might be more productive to make that a feature request rather than just posting an open-ended question like this. But, I'd put a lot more thought into your suggestion before you do post it.

Comment: Well I didn't want to ask a feature if it already existed! :) Would you suggest a new question or editing this?

Comment: @dav_i - Up to you.