# How can I improve the visibility of my question?

Tags: discussion, questions

When I post a question on Stack Overflow, I don't get a lot of views quickly, which reduces the number of possible answers.

What should I do to increase the views on my question?

Comment: Time of day seems to be a factor.  Also the question should be well written with a clear statement of the problem and enough supporting code without a wall of useless extra code to wade through.  The title should give a clear indication of what the issue is.  Use appropriate tags to attract the attention the right audience.

Comment: Of course there's also... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046 | http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16874 | http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1313 which you could have found if you searched for the question before asking...

Comment: Thank you, next time i will do more search!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure this has been answered a thousand times before but I would suggest:

- Time of day.  Some times are more active than others but there is always someone around.
- The question should be a clear statement of the problem.
- No wall of code or not enough code.  There should be enough to give the context of your problem but not so much that you can't see where the problem may lie.
- The title should be clear and indicate exactly what your problem is.  Don't embed tags in your title.
- Use the appropriate tags to attract the audience who may be able to answer your question.
- How esoteric is your topic?  Some are simply more popular than others and will be answered more quickly.

It all depends on the popularity of the topic you are asking and the number of people who are able to help.  That's really the crux of it :)

Comment: [Related post and more information about time of day factor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251768/number-of-answers-depending-on-time-asked)

Comment: @gunr2171 I've certainly experienced it myself when the time of day has had an impact when I get a response.  It's good to see quantifiable statistics of that :)

Comment: What time in UTC i'm adviced to post my question on it?

Comment: The link posted by @gunr2171 is in UTC.  Between 1500 to 2200 is your best option.

Comment: I have asked only 7 questions in total. None of them is downvoted. I am not getting why am I banned from asking questions . I am not sure whom to ask.You seem to know lot about questions. Please help me!!