# Number of answers per question depending on hour of week

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions, data-explorer, time

I'm trying to find out how the *average number of answers per question* and the *average number of accepted answers per question* depend on the time (in GMT) **and** day of the week of when a question is **asked**.

For example if 1,000,000 questions were posted on all Tuesdays between 2pm and 3pm and 700,000 out of them have accepted answers, then that number is 0.7 for that time slot. Other numbers for other days of the week and other hours.

What I'm looking for is something that would represent this data showing every hour of the week. Ideally, it should look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/reW5Z.png]

##### Note: The image does NOT show the real data of course, otherwise I wouldn't ask. This is just a sketch, please help me get the real data.

While [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251768/number-of-answers-depending-on-time-asked) is slightly related (and the SEDE query from it might help but requires strong modifications), it has immense differences to my question:

- Days of the week are not considered.
- As [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251768/number-of-answers-depending-on-time-asked#comment221101_251768) points out, the statistic in the question does not consider the number of answers *per question*.
- For statistics about answers, the SEDE query ignores when **the question of that answer** was posted, and only considers the time of the answer itself.

Comment: How would this data be useful to you? What would you be planning to do with it?

Comment: so **most** live in europe or america and they have their wake-sleep-work rhythm.

Comment: "*So the plot would look something like this, showing every hour of the week*" Um... did you ask and answer yourself here? I am a little confused about what you are asking...

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 This is NOT the data. This is just a sketch.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question has received so many downvotes. Perhaps because it wasn't clear or maybe users don't think there's a valid use case for this. Perhaps try to address Cody's comment above. Anyway, I tried to reword the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Just earn 25k reputation, then you'll be able to see the Site Analytics! ;)

Comment: I'm still confused what data you actually want. "number of answers per question", okay. "number of accepted answers per question" is what exactly? There can be only one accepted answer per question – do you mean how often the OP changed their decision? Whether they accepted any question? "[time] when a question is asked" is well-defined, but is it actually useful for the data? Are you sure there is causation and not just correlation? For that matter, what are the blue and orange lines in your example plot?

Comment: #answers based on when the question was asked:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1428363#graph

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I mean the average number of (accepted) answers per question. So for example if 1,000,000 questions were posted on Tuesday between 2pm and 3pm and 700,000 out of them have accepted answers, then that number is 0.7 for that time slot.

Comment: That's the total number of answers. You would have to divide it by the number of questions to get the average.

Comment: fine with me: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1428363#graph

Comment: @rene Awesome, thank you! So every day there's a three-hour slot for asking that yields *more* answers, and paradoxically *fewer accepted* answers. Do I read your plot correctly? (questions without answers get ignored?)

Comment: sounds about right yes.

Comment: @rene Here I'm trying to take unanswered questions into consideration (not sure about correct usage of SEDE): https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1428395/when-to-ask-questions#graph

Comment: I don't think that makes sense without taking the total number of questions into account, or at least error bands. There are about 3 times less questions during these slots, so the statistics won't be entirely comparable. Just averaging hides quite a lot of information.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The error bands are small. The effect is statistically significant and the effect size is noticeable. The number of samples does not influence that, just like flipping a coin more often doesn't influence the probability of getting heads during each flip. What comparability *does* suffer from though are other confounders such as [different programming languages](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/19/programming-languages-used-late-night/). That can be analyzed in a separate question.

Comment: @root "effect is statistically significant" looking forward to seeing the full analysis that supports this statement.

Comment: @CodyGray "How would this data be useful to you? What would you be planning to do with it?" Hopefully publishing it. It makes sense to ask questions at times when answerers are online. Especially in a scenario, where questions get forgotten quickly because they are a dime a dozen.

Comment: @Trilarion Is that really what the data would reveal? This entire query seems made for jumping to conclusions. It looks like the chance to get *an* answer is pretty static – so is the issue for *acceptable* answers the answers or the questions, or even the answerers or the questioners? Does it really make sense to ask questions when the site is already flooded with questions, instead of waiting for a time when there is much less  competition? Are the averages actually meaningful, or are they just a meaningless superposition of different effects for different categories?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think it's a valid question, whatever the outcome is. And if there is a little bit of advantage to gain by asking at the right time, it's good if it's used because it'll make SO better. Also by exploring timing if possible you'll basically make everything more equal so that the majority of people can safely ask questions whenever they may have them.

Comment: @Trilarion I also think it's a valid and interesting question. What I'm concerned about are the conclusions drawn from it. For example "It makes sense to ask questions at times when answerers are online." – that's just not covered by the data.